# Codename One - Star Ranking

Tags: codenameone

[image: StarRankSlider]

After I click the Feedback button, I want it to move to a new form. In that form, it has star rank. I have the code but I don't know how to make the star rank appear on the form. Please show me how to do it.

Comment: Please do not post image of your code, but put your code in the Question and format it with the icon `code`. Take a look here : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
Form f = new Form("Feedback", BoxLayout.y());
f.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(createStarRankSlider()));
f.add(new TextField("", "Feedback", 20, TextField.ANY));
Button ok = new Button("Send");
ok.addActionListener(e -> goToNextForm());
f.show();
```